# Customize Upload.aspx page

Tags: sharepoint

I have to customise the multiple upload functionalityof sharepoint:

Requirement: 
On multiple upload I want the system to trigger a single email (containing names of all the files uploaded)at the end of all uploads. The emails ids,subject and body of the mail muct be editable to the user(must appear as a UI)

Can someone please suggest a solution for the same.

Thanks!
Payal Smriti

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [SharePoint Timer jobs](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/CreatingCustomSharePointTimerJobs.aspx) to query all items on list which have been created lately?

Query would be SOMETHING like

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Leq>
      <FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'><Today/></Value>
    </Leq>
    <Ge>
      <FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>{0}</Value> 
    </Ge>
   </And>
</Where
```

>

Where at {0} you can use [SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587646(v=office.11).aspx)([this.LastRunTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjobdefinition.lastruntime(v=office.14).aspx))